# html5 websocket can not connect to c server

Tags: c, html, websocket

i wrote a html5 client and a c server, when  client attemped to connect to server, seems from client alert message, it connect success(onopen function called) and then connection was closed(onerror function called first, then onclose function called). After client closed the connection, server received  SIGPIPE signal and exit.

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
        <title>C Websocket Test</title>

        <script>
            var websocket;
            var wsUri = "ws://localhost:49880";
            //var wsUri = "wss://echo.websocket.org";

            function connect() {
                try {
                    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

                    websocket.onopen = function(msg) {
                        alert('websocket_onopen: connect success');
                    }

                    websocket.onclose = function(msg) {
                        alert('websocket_onclose: status - ' + this.readyState);
                    }

                    websocket.onmessage = function(msg) {
                        alert('server says: ' + msg.data);
                    }

                    websocket.onerror = function(msg) {
                        alert('websocket_onerror: connect error - ' + msg);
                    }
                } catch (E) {
                    alert('try connect error' + E);
                    return;
                }           
            }

            function send() {

                websocket.send('hello, i am websocket client');
            } 

            function close() {
                websocket.close();
            } 
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="msg" type="text">
        <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
        <button id="send" onclick="send();">Send</button>
        <button id="close" onclick="close();">Close</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define LISTENING_PORT 49880
#define MAXLENGTH 1024 + 1

char *get_websocket_key(char *request, char *buf, size_t buf_len)
{
    size_t len;
    char *key = "Sec-WebSocket-Key:";
    char *end, *start = strstr(request, key);

    start += strlen(key) + 1;
    end = start;

    while (*end != '\n' && *end != '\r') {
        ++end;
    }

    len = end -start;

    if (len >= buf_len)
        return NULL;

    memcpy(buf, start, len);
    buf[len] = '\0';

    return buf;
}

char *base64_encode(const char *data, size_t data_len, char *out, size_t out_len)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int len;

    int fd = open(".base64_src", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (write(fd, data, data_len) != data_len) {
        perror("write");
        return NULL;
    }

    close(fd);

    if ( (fp = popen("base64 .base64_src", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        return NULL;
    }

    len = 0;
    while (fgets(out + len, out_len - len, fp) != NULL) {
        len = strlen(out);
        out[--len] = '\0';
    }

    if (out[len - 1] == '\n')
        out[len - 1] = '\0';

    pclose(fp);
    system("rm .base64_src");

    return out;
}

void parsestr(char *request,char *data)
{
    int needle;
    char sec_key[1024], encrypt_key[1024], buf[1024];

    memset(request, 0, sizeof(request));
    get_websocket_key(data, sec_key, sizeof(sec_key));
    //printf("[== original-key]:[%s]\n", sec_key);
    strcat(sec_key, "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
    SHA1(sec_key, strlen(sec_key), encrypt_key);
    //printf("[base64_encode]: [%s]\n", base64_encode(encrypt_key, strlen(encrypt_key), sec_key, sizeof(sec_key)));
    base64_encode(encrypt_key, strlen(encrypt_key), sec_key, sizeof(sec_key));
    strcpy(request, "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n");
    strcat(request, "Upgrade: websocket\r\n");
    strcat(request, "Connection: Upgrade\r\n");
    sprintf(encrypt_key, "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: %s\r\n", sec_key);
    strcat(request, encrypt_key);
    strcat(request, "\r\n");
}

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    printf("[Signal Received: %d]\n", signo);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, len, ret, client_fd;
    int reuse = 1;
    fd_set rwfd;
    struct sockaddr_in s_addr, client_addr;
    struct timeval tv;

    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(int));
    if (server_fd < 0)
        perror("socket");

    s_addr.sin_port = htons(LISTENING_PORT);
    s_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0)
        perror("bind");

    if (listen(server_fd, 5) < 0)
        perror("listen");

    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    signal(SIGPIPE, sig_handler);

    while (1) {
        char buf[MAXLENGTH], request[MAXLENGTH];
        int responsed = 0;

        client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &len);

        if (client_fd < 0) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("%s connected.\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));
        }

        while (1) {
            int retval, maxfd;

            FD_ZERO(&rwfd);
            FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rwfd);
            FD_SET(client_fd, &rwfd);

            maxfd = client_fd > STDIN_FILENO ? client_fd : STDIN_FILENO;

            if (select(maxfd + 1, &rwfd, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0) {
                perror("select");
                continue;
            } else {
                if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &rwfd)) {
                    fgets(buf, MAXLENGTH, stdin);
                    parsestr(request, buf);

                    if (send(client_fd, request, MAXLENGTH, 0) > 0) 
                        printf("[ Console Server send: ]\n%s\n", request);
                }

                if (FD_ISSET(client_fd, &rwfd)) {
                    len = recv(client_fd, buf, MAXLENGTH, 0);

                    if ( (len > 0) && (strncmp(buf, "quit", 4) == 0)) {
                        printf("Client request close connect.\n");
                        close(client_fd);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        printf("[Client send: ]\n%s\n", buf);
                        //if (!responsed) {
                        if (1) {
                            //responsed = 1;
                            if (responsed == 0) {
                                responsed = 1;
                                parsestr(request, buf);
                            }
                            if (send(client_fd, request, MAXLENGTH, 0) > 0) {
                                printf("[Server send: ]\n%s\n", request);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } /* if (FD_ISSET(client_fd, &rwfd)) */
            }

        } // while (1)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

server log:

```
vincent@Vincent:/mnt/share/websocket$ ./a.out 
127.0.0.1 connected.
[Client send: ]
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:49880
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: XZaYANDATZBlVK9B3zIcOA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.14 Safari/537.36

[Server send: ]
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: DkeUbVTGuGuFSRO7YXwHyWZNsgc=


[Client send: ]
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:49880
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: XZaYANDATZBlVK9B3zIcOA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.14 Safari/537.36


[Server send: ]
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: DkeUbVTGuGuFSRO7YXwHyWZNsgc=


[Client send: ]
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:49880
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: XZaYANDATZBlVK9B3zIcOA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.14 Safari/537.36


[Signal Received: 13]
```

i checkd websocket protocol and seems format of response is right. is anybody know what's wrong of the server? thanks in advance!